# Camera Calibration Intrinsic Matrix what do the values represent?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, camera-calibration

So I did a camera calibration using the checkerboard and the matlab camera calibration toolbox. So the Intrinsic Matrix that I obtained for that particular session is as follows:

Intrinsic Matrix: [349.3601,0,0;0,349.7267,0;258.0883,210.5905,1]

I have been trying to search the meaning of those values in the matrix but has been unsuccessful so far.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thank you for your reply. Okay so in the screenshot above (see edits) you can see there is the Intrinsic matrix. I am trying to get the focal length of the camera and its exact mid point. So from this intrinsic matrix, which one is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [official MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/cameraparameters-class.html), the intrinsic matrix is defined as follows:

[image]

where `fx = F*sx`, `fy = F*sy`, `F` is the focal length in world units, typically expressed in millimeters and `[sx, sy]` are the number of pixels per world unit in the x and y direction respectively. `fx` and `fy`are expressed in pixels.

Comment: thank you for pointing this out. okay so from the above, how can I obtain F, the focal length? I cannot seem to find sx and sy

Comment: Google the specification of the sensor of you camera, look for things named "dot pitch" (pixels / mm) or "active sensor dimensions" (width, height in mm)